# Shouldn't fuzzy version of a solr query always return a super set of its not-fuzzy equivalent

Tags: search, solr, fuzzy-search

I'm using the following query to do a fuzzy search on Solr 4.5.1 and am getting empty result.

```
qt=standard&q=+(field1|en_CA|:Swimming~2 field1|en|:Swimming~2) +(field1|en_CA|:Goggle~1 field1|en|:Goggle~1) +(+startDate:[* TO 2013-12-04T00:23:00Z] -endDate:[* TO 2013-12-04T00:23:00Z])&start=0&rows=10&fl=id
```

If I change it to a not fuzzy query by simply dropping tildes from the terms (see below) then it returns the expected result! Is this a bug? Shouldn't fuzzy version of a query always return a super set of its not-fuzzy equivalent?

```
qt=standard&q=+(field1|en_CA|:Swimming field1|en|:Swimming) +(field1|en_CA|:Goggle field1|en|:Goggle) +(+startDate:[* TO 2013-12-04T00:23:00Z] -endDate:[* TO 2013-12-04T00:23:00Z])&start=0&rows=10&fl=id
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should match, Unless all you have is only fuzzier version of the data.
In other words do you have a word "Swimming" in your data that was indexed?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I got on lucene-solr-user mailing list:

> Chances are you're not getting those fuzzy terms analyzed as you'd
>   like. See debug (&debug=true) output to be sure.  Most likely the
>   fuzzy terms are not being lowercased.  See
>   http://wiki.apache.org/solr/MultitermQueryAnalysis for more details
>   (this applies to fuzzy, not just wildcard) terms too.

After further analysis It turned out that, in my case, it was stemmer filter causing the issue. Adding the following to the filed type fixed the issue :-)

```
<analyzer type="multiterm" >
<tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
<filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English"/>
</analyzer>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation for Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html#Fuzzy%20Searches), on which Solr is built, fuzzy search syntax is expressed as a value between 0 and 1.  So your query would be:

q=+(field1|en_CA|:Swimming~**0.2** field1|en|:Swimming~**0.2**)....

instead of

q=+(field1|en_CA|:Swimming~**2** field1|en|:Swimming~**2**)....

Hope this helps!